# Auto-respond to a mailitem read receipt using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

Many times senders requesting a read receipt where my code stops processing inbox until I press <Y/N> on the pop-up read receipt box (MSO). Is there a way to auto-respond to those requests?

Comment: Edit the question to add the code. The behaviour described is not normal.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the [MailItem.ReadReceiptRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.readreceiptrequested) property which returns a boolean value that indicates `true` if a read receipt has been requested by the sender. It is read-only for sent email items.

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for responding to such requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the Outlook Object Model.

You can do that on the Extended MAPI level (C++ or Delphi only) - call `IMessage::SetReadFlag()` - pass 0 to send a read receipt or `SUPPRESS_RECEIPT` (1) constant otherwise.

If [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes the [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).`MarkRead` method that takes a `SuppressReceipt` Boolean parameter.

Comment: Nice to know a possible workaround using Extended MAPI.